# Array.map { |x| change value } is removing it from the array, why?

Tags: ruby, arrays, dictionary, enumerable

The objective is to move each letter to the next letter in the alphabet,
within the map, it successfully changed the letter but once i'm out of there the value disappears, except the vowels. How come?

```
def LetterChanges(str)
  abc = [*("a".."z")]

  result = str.split(//)

  result.map! do |x| 

  if abc.include?(x)

    if x == "z"
       x = "A"
       else
       x = abc[abc.index(x)+1]

       # if you puts x here, you can see it changes value correctly

       if x == "a" || x == "e" || x == "i" || x == "o" || x == "u"
          x.capitalize!
          end
       end
    end

    #However here, the changed values that are not vowels disappear 
    # WHY is that happening, is the second if (vowel) affecting it? How?

end
puts "#{result.join}"  #<--- its only putting the vowels
return result.join  

end

LetterChanges("what the hell is going on?")
```

Comment: What is your block's value when the character (`x`) is not in `abc`? How about if `x` is `'w'`? Step through the code by hand or in a debugger. Or convert it to a lambda (`f = lambda do |x| if abc.include?(x) ... end`) so that you can easily evaluate the block in `irb` with various inputs.

Comment: thanks mu - if its not in abc, i want that same value so i thought it would just keep the (x) value if it didn't meet any of the if's conditions. How come that doesn't happen? What makes (x) loose the value it took when created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block passed to `map!` needs to return a value in all cases for this to work.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21

```
def LetterChanges(str)
  abc = [*("a".."z")]

  result = str.split(//)

  result.map! do |x| 
    if abc.include?(x)
      if x == "z"
         x = "A"
      else
         x = abc[abc.index(x)+1]
         if x == "a" || x == "e" || x == "i" || x == "o" || x == "u"
            x.capitalize!
          end
      end
    end
    x
  end

  result.join  
end
```

Comment: thanks Daniel, quick question: if its going through each x, why does it not return x if it does not meet the criteria for all if's ?

Comment: The value returned by the block of code passed to `map!` is the last expression that gets evaluated. An `if` that is `false` evaluates to `nil` so if the execution reaches `if x == "a" || x == "e" || x == "i" || x == "o" || x == "u"` with a letter that's not a vowel then the block would return `nil` without the explicit `x` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your if. When *x* is a not a vowel that return nil.

Just Change this line

```
if x == "a" || x == "e" || x == "i" || x == "o" || x == "u"
    x.capitalize!
end
```

With this

```
x = %w{a e i o u}.include?(x) ? x.capitalize : x
```

Comment: thanks Daniel, hey whats going on here: "%w{a e i o u}"  as in, what is "%w" saying and how come "%w{ t h e s e  d o n t  n e e d  c o m m a s?}"  i believe you it works, but i want to understand that shortcode

Comment: Is other format to create array. with %w i say the elements are separate with spaces, {} are the limits so
    %{a e i o u} == ["a","e","i","o","u"]

Comment: Can I suggest the docs on Ruby literals: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html